# Textbox height is too much

Tags: java, android, xml

Please have a look at the following XML layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/lblPassword"
        android:text="@string/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pwdText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        />


    <Button 
        android:text="@string/btnLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="showMessage"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

This generates the following gui (attached)
[image]

As you can see, the textbox height is unexpectedly too much. Actually what I need is adjusting textbox width to fit to the app properly, providing enough space to type (if I didn't do anything, the textbox appears very small in width). I am new to android. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand the width to match the width of the device replace `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` with `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, or you can specify a width in dp.

By setting the attributes `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` you are saying you want this elements height to fill all the remaining space on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Does it fix the issue when u remove this line `android:layout_height="0dp"`

edit: or change it to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 1):

change your EditText to this

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/pwdText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "match_parent" attribute for either width or height for your outermost layout. Use either wrap_content or fill_parent. Also replace 0dp in the layout_height for the editText with wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

For the text View height change it from wrap content to 10 dp.